# Interfaces, hiding concrete implementation details in C++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a question regarding hidinging interface details in C++ libraries. The problem is ilustrated with the following example:

Let's say w have a class called ***ISystem*** which exposes methods like *Init, Run, Tick, Shutdown, GetXXXSubSystem.*
Where X are pointers various interfaces like: *ISoundSystem, IInputSystem*

We also have concrete implementations of ISystem like:
***Win32System, OSXSystem*** etc.

These specific implementations use a pimpl idiom to hide internals
and for example Win32System instantiates **Win32RawInputSystem**
as input system manager.

All such managers do have their own *Init, Run, Tick and Shutdown* methods
which are not part of the interface (only concrete implementation) and these are run and managed by the concrete system implementation.

The user calling GetXXXSubSystem gets interface pointer without those methods (Init etc..) but
still he could cast the pointer he gets to concrete implementation
and trigger methods like Init Run Tick etc. which he shouldn't have access to.

The question is, is it possible to hide the concrete class somehow? I tried to make those methods
protected in the concrete implementations and template the class on type which would eventually be friend but this appears to be prohobited and existing hacks do not work with VC11.

The only way I can think of right know is to transfer the concrete implementation declaration from header
into the cpp file of Win32System class but I see  ahuge drawback of doing this (even not sure if this would work), because this way each subsystem
would have to be also part of this cpp file and it would become a maintainability nightmare.

Another solution I am thinking about is using factory method like

```
(RawInput.h) 
IInputSystem* CreateRawInputSystem();

(RawInput.cpp)
class RawInput : public IInputSystem {}; ...
```

and move definition of the class to cpp file but then, how I would acces this type from other parts of my library (ie in Win32System impl)?

Is it possible to include .cpp files form other .cpp files?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: C++'s internal "security" features (e.g., `private:`/`protected:`) are intended to protect against accidents, not intentional abuse. As a general rule, I'd advise that you do the same (largely because almost any attempt to the contrary is doomed to absolute failure from the beginning).

Comment: The thing is that I need to expose some class functionalities of concrete implementations to internals of my library without the possibility for the library user. Maybe I am missing some design pattern that lets me achieve this.

Comment: No. What you're looking for is closer to an OS than a design pattern. Make the code work and make it apparent what parts a user *shouldn't* use directly. For the internals of the code, even attempting more is  a waste of time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing a library here, then you can simply choose not to export the header files of the concrete classes that you do not want to expose. You cannot cast to a class of which you do not have a definition.

Example :
**MyProjectFolder/Src/Export/ISystem.h**

```
#ifndef ISYSTEM_H
#define ISYSTEM_H

#include "IInputSystem.h"

class ISystem
{
public:
    virtual ~ISystem() {};
    virtual void Run()=0;
    virtual IInputSystem* GetInputSystem()=0;
};

#endif
```

**MyProjectFolder/Src/Export/IInputSystem.h**

```
#ifndef IINPUTSYSTEM_H
#define IINPUTSYSTEM_H

class IInputSystem
{
public:
    virtual ~IInputSystem() {};
    virtual void Foo()=0;
    virtual void Bar()=0;
};

#endif
```

**MyProjectFolder/Src/Export/Win32System.h**

```
#ifndef WIN32SYSTEM_H
#define WIN32SYSTEM_H

#include "ISystem.h"

class Win32System : public ISystem
{
public:
    Win32System();
    virtual void Run();
    virtual IInputSystem* GetInputSystem();

private:
    struct impl;
    impl* m_pImpl;
};

#endif
```

**MyProjectFolder/Src/Win32RawInputSystem.h**

```
#ifndef WIN32RAWINPUTSYSTEM_H
#define WIN32RAWINPUTSYSTEM_H

#include "IInputSystem.h"

class Win32RawInputSystem : public IInputSystem
{
public:
    virtual void Foo();
    virtual void Bar();

    virtual void Run(); // you do not want to expose that function
};

#endif
```

**MyProjectFolder/Src/Win32System.cpp**

```
#include "Win32System.h"

#include "Win32RawInputSystem.h"

struct Win32System::impl
{
    Win32RawInputSystem inputSys;
};

Win32System::Win32System()
 : m_pImpl(new impl)
{
}

void Win32System::Run()
{ // run run run
}

IInputSystem* Win32System::GetInputSystem()
{
    return &m_pImpl->inputSys;
}
```

So when building your project its include search path is not only *Src/* but also *Src/Export/*. From within your library project you can use all classes, including Win32RawInputSystem. When deploying your library you only give away those headers that reside in the *Src/Export/* folder. Clients can still use the library, but they can never cast `IInputSystem*` to `Win32RawInputSystem*` because they do not have that header. Therefore the users of that library can invoke `Foo()` and `Bar()` on the `IInputSystem*`, but they'll never be able to invoke `Run()`.

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I meant by saying hiding a type. In fact the solution is so simple that I am amazed I had a problem with that. 

And to be frank, I "lied" when said about not being able to define a template argument as a friend. This solution (a feature of C++11) is implemented in VC11 so it works fine, I have messed something up. The syntax is friend T, where T is template type.